# Custom error messages for html form elements with array names in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-6, validationerror

I'm having trouble getting custom perr-field validation error messages to display in my form.  I would much appreciate help to resolve this.

I've used Laravel validations a lot and so understand the principles, but the issue I'm currently having a problem with is displaying a custom message for a html element with a name that's an array.

I have 'sets' of fields, which are replicated upon the click of a button.  Each set is created using an incrementing index value, which distinguishes one set from the other:

```
<div id="divSet1">
    <input type='text' 
        class="form-control @error('form_fields[1][surname]') is-invalid @enderror" 
        id="form_fields_1_surname" name="form_fields[1][surname]" />
    @error('form_fields[1][surname]')
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
    @enderror
    
    .
    .
    . more fields here
    .
    .

</div>

<div id="divSet2">
    <input type='text' 
        class="form-control @error('form_fields[2][surname]') is-invalid @enderror" 
        id="form_fields_2_surname" name="form_fields[2][surname]" />
    @error('form_fields[2][surname]')
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
    @enderror
    
    .
    .
    . more fields here
    .
    .
</div>
```

The FormRequest class:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;


/**
 * Application form request
 * 
 * @category controllers 
 * @sub-category validation
 */
class FormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'form_fields.*.surname' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'form_fields.*.surname.required' => 'Please supply a surname',
        ];
    }

}
```

When I submit the form, I don't see the custom error messages for the failed surname fields.  The fields aren't even highlighted in red.

However, if I add a validation error message general banner supplied in the Laravel documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors), the missing surnames are reported:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

While this works and will indeed reports the missing surnames at the top of the page without the custom messages:

```
* Please supply a surname  // <-- form_fields[1][surname]
* Please supply a surname  // <-- form_fields[2][surname]
```

.. this isn't the individualized custom errors displayed beneath the invalid fields.

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like

```
@error('form_fields.2.surname')
 <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Comment: Thanks @zeref, that resolved it for me.  Maybe this should be added to the Laravel documentation?